# throw new TypeError('The super constructor to "inherits" must not ' +

Tags: node.js, npm, spdy

I am trying to build my nodejs application. but i am always getting this error.

```
util.js:988
throw new TypeError('The super constructor to "inherits" must not ' +
^

TypeError: The super constructor to "inherits" must not be null or undefined
at Object.inherits (util.js:988:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\CIDE-Backend\CIDE-BACKEND\node_modules\zetta\node_modules\spdy\lib\spdy\connection.js:86:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\CIDE-Backend\CIDE-BACKEND\node_modules\zetta\node_modules\spdy\lib\spdy.js:20:19)
at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

i followed this [solution](https://github.com/nodeftpd/nodeftpd/issues/124) but still i am getting same error.

`my node version is 8.4.0`

`my npm version is 5.5.1`

Can you tell me how can i solve this error.?

Comment: The spdy module (one of your dependencies) not behaves. Try to figure out what other dependency requires that. Latest spdy source does not even have that file. (See https://github.com/spdy-http2/node-spdy/tree/master/lib/spdy) Maybe upgrading your deps can solve the issue.

Comment: still same error

Answer (score 4):

Your dependency `zetta` is including an ancient version of `spdy` which is not compatible with you current version of Node. There is currently an open issue on [zetta's github](https://github.com/zettajs/zetta/issues/336) about this, which has a work around:

```
process.EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter
const zetta = require('zetta')
```

Your mileage may vary on that hack, I have not tested it myself. Alternatively, you could wait for the zetta team to fix their dependency or downgrade your node installation.